# Which Airport Is Good For Layover LHR, FRA, TXL, HAM?

Tags: airports, layovers, activities

I'm booking a flight from EWR to MUC and all my options have a 4 hour layover at either LHR, FRA, TXL, HAM, or GVA.

Which would be the best for my layover (morning until afternoon)?

I will have two small children in tow (9 and 6).  I was considering FRA since it would give the longest overnight leg for us to sleep, but am interested in what the other airports might have to offer.  I will also have access to the Star Alliance lounge.

Comment: Is a train from Frankfurt to Munich an option (about 4 hours travel time)?

Comment: Will that be the same terminal at LHR? Otherwise you may use some of your time transiting between terminals making the delights or other wise of LHR less relevant.

Comment: FRA. Plenty of really good LH lounges and there are plenty of shops and even a supermarket (you need land side though). Many playgrounds too: https://www.frankfurt-airport.com/en/travel/transfer.detail.suffix.html/service/at-the-airport/play-areas.html . It's a huge airport so there will be some hiking involved